# XPath to select elements with exclusions (with multiple sub elements)

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following type of XML: -

```
  <tagCategory name="Bike" id="10">
  </tagCategory>
  <tagCategory name="Cars" id="22">
    <excludedClass>NonDriver</excludedClass>
    <excludedClass>BannedFromDriving</excludedClass>
  </tagCategory>
  <tagCategory name="PogoStick" id="5">
<excludedClass>NoLegs</excludedClass>
  </tagCategory>
```

I want to run queries where I can say: -

Give me all the tagCategory elements where the excludedClass isn't X. For example: -

- Give me all the tagCategory elements where the excludedClass isn't 'NoLegs' should return Cars and Bike.
- Give me all the tagCategory elements where the excludedClass isn't 'BannedFromDriving' should return Bike and PogoStick.
- Give me all the tagCategory elements where the excludedClass isn't 'NonDriver' should return Bike and PogoStick.

I'm using the current XPath and it handles the elements with only one excludedClass but where multiple are present it doesn't filter the items out as I'd expect.

`"//tagCategory[excludedClass!='" + classification + "' or not(excludedClass)]"`

Does anyone have any ideas how I can modify my XPath to give me what I need?

Really appreciate any ideas.

Kind regards,

Phil.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4 so whatever is in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
//tagCategory[not(excludedClass='NonDriver')]
```

example:

```
//tagCategory[not(excludedClass='" + classification + "')]
```

Comment: David, the thing is, I can only pass in one exclusion, i.e. the one I know about, I don't know about the others. Is there not a way to do that?

Comment: @PhilWinstanley - Sorry...I misread the question. Please see my edit and see if that works for you.

Comment: Perfect - thank you, I also had to pop the or not(excludedClass) to cater for items where it's not present :)

Comment: @PhilWinstanley - Actually the xpath in my answer also handles items where there are no `excludedClass` elements present. (That's why I only used `not()` and didn't use `!=`)